ubuntu 22.04.4 problem when installing Rstudio, server not listening to port 8787
I just installed Rstudio (RSTUDIO-2024.04.1-748-AMD64.DEB opensouce) on Ubuntu 22 server. Installation went thru without any error, I did add (allow) port 8787 to firewall, when I run netstat -tulpn it seems the server not listening to 8787, this couse not be able to reach the server via http://xxxx.xx:8787. I have done this severel time on ubuntu 20 without any problem. Any idea? thks

A complete and proper version info is always a good start. There is no version of Ubuntu simply called 20 and 22.

Jammy for 22 and focal 20

Those are code names not version numbers. A version number would be like 22.04.4

sorry it is 22.04.4

Did you install RStudio Server - or RStudio Desktop? The .deb name "RSTUDIO-2024.04.1-748-AMD64.DEB" suggests the latter

desktop I gues, Rstudio server is licensed

Thank you steeldriver!! your question nailded, when I installed the serverversion everything works nice now, thank you again!!:)

Thank you all: It was my bad, when I downloaded the server version of Rstudio it worked perfektly here is the link RStudio for ubuntu 22.04.4
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/jammy/amd64/rstudio-server-2024.04.1-748-amd64.deb
